# Parse.com cloud code httprequest status code 200 zero bytes returned

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, httprequest, gzip

I'm trying to make a httprequest from Parse.com cloud code, but although it returns response status code 200, it doesn't have any data with it (content-length: 0).

Because of my company privacy I can't post an URL on which the request fails, however it returns data successfully when used on http://www.seznam.cz/ or https://gmail.com/ (which returns 301 as a redirection issue, but still succeeds), so it's not caused by a https thing (my url is an api url with https)

Do you have an idea of why would the request succeed but return zero bytes, when in browser the data loads correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can one access that API URL from anywhere or are there any restrictions, such as those based on originating IP.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, though I thought it's accessible from anywhere! Do you think that could be the issue, really? Interesting.. I shall ask the owner of the api! Thanks for the tip

Comment: To answer C Abernathy, Yes, you can access api from anywhere. Maybe the issue is related to the fact that the response get gziped. Do you know something about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that parse.com `httpRequest` doesn't use gzip decompression, and the api does, so although it received the response, nothing was returned since no data could be get.

I've overcome this issue by writing a php script posted on my web which get's the api's response, and prints it afterwards, therefore parse.com's `httpRequest` doesn't need to decompress the gzip and everything works as expected. I needed the same for images, by the way.